# How to make a variable store certain code to rerun again

Tags: python, macros

I'm making a macro as a project but can't figure out how to store code in a variable and then use the variable again

```
import pyautogui
import time
minimize = (pyautogui.click(1811, 14))
Start = (pyautogui.click(1825, 997), pyautogui.click(1825, 997))
place = (pyautogui.click(1708, 751), time.sleep(0.1), pyautogui.click(770, 478))
```

When I run the code now it does what's been typed out but I want it to ignore the code in the beginning and then I can use it again by calling upon a variable example "place"

I tried to mess around with the code for a bit but I only got errors

Comment: "Code that you can call later" is a *function*.  Try `def minimize():` / `pyautogui.click(1811, 14)`, and then later do `minimize()`, for example.

Comment: 1. "I tried to mess around with the code for a bit" - *what* did you try? 2. "I only got errors" - *what* errors? Please [edit] your question to show what you tried, and always include any error traceback in the body of your question. That said, @jasonharper is right - what you're looking for is a [function](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/)

Comment: The way to store "code to be executed" is by defining a function.

Comment: For something more complex than you can put in a lambda, you can define a mini-language that gets interpreted.

Comment: Or if the code is always generated internally, you could store source code in a string and use `exec()` to execute it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback function is what was needed, thank you everybody for your help